# VR Compatibility: Moto G6 vs E5 Play

Tags: motorola-moto-g, samsung-gear-vr

I hope this is the correct place to ask this (they directed me here from Meta Exchange).

I'm starting to program in VR with Unity (for Android) and I'm looking to get a low-cost smartphone with VR support. My phone company offered me free either a Moto G6 Play or a Moto E5 Play.

According to their specifications, both are VR capable (gyroscope and motion sensor included). However, I've read mixed reviews online, so I would like to confirm if both are really VR compatible and which would be best for testing gaming related media.

Comment: This is partially on-topic. The part about VR confirmation is on-topic, but what would be best is opinionated, so such questions are usually closed. I suggest you edit that out. XDA and Reddit are better platforms for opinions.

Comment: Thanks. That's why I asked in meta exchange if this question was allowed and they told me that I shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Did you delete your question there? I can't see a question for your account on Meta SE.

Answer (score 0):

Neither device is supported by [Samsung Gear VR](https://support.oculus.com/597800887090482/) or [Google Daydream](https://support.google.com/daydream/answer/9232592?hl=en&ref_topic=7105096)

One of the requirements for Daydream certification is to have [motion to photon latency of 22ms-25ms](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-talks-about-the-certification-process-for-daydream-at-ces-2017/).

Curiously the Motorola Moto G6 is supported by [Google ARCore](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) which is expected to have [sensors be calibrated in a similar fashion to Daydream](https://medium.com/6d-ai/how-is-arcore-better-than-arkit-5223e6b3e79d)

For everything else there is 
[Google Cardboard](https://vr.google.com/cardboard/) which takes advantage of accelerometer/gyroscope on phone. As the sensor measurements/screen latency aren't strictly calibrated the experiences are more static and for brief sessions to avoid motion sickness.